# React axios fetching from different URL then set in enviroment

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to set a "development" and "production" environment from within my react app.
I made an `.env.development.local` file and inside added:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL = “http://localhost:3001”
REACT_APP_ENV = “dev”
```

then in my `package.json` I added

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV='dev' npm run start"
  },
```

now in a component, I am trying to access the `REACT_APP_API_URL`

```
const API_URI = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
```

```
  const fetchGuess = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URI}/characters/random`);
    if (data.success) {
      setToGuess(data.data);
    } else {
      console.log("ERROR", data.errorMessage);
    }
  };
'
```

In the response, I see this as the URL axios is trying to fetch from

`http://localhost:3000 /%E2%80%9C http://localhost:3001%E2%80%9D/characters/random`

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: Try removing double quotes in your .env file.

Comment: @CaferElgin ah nice that fixed it right up